# Iterating through rows where rows could be "missing"

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table with multiple rows with a column for ordering these rows. And then I have an expired column and a data column:

```
|ordering|  expired |  data  |
------------------------------
|    1   |2020-12-31|whatever|
|    2   |2020-12-31|whatever|
|    3   |2020-12-31|whatever|
|    4   |2010-01-01|whatever|
|    5   |2020-12-31|whatever|
```

I also have a table with the line number for which I last got:

```
|number|
|------|
|   2  |
```

I get that number and add 1 to get the next line I need. Then I check if that number is higher than the rowcount and got back to 1 if it is. I store the new line back into number so I can use that the next time I need a row.

This is working perfectly except I filter the results by expired. In the above example row 4 will not be selected. So when I get the row with ordering=4 then the result will be empty. Of course it is easy to fix - if I get an empty results I can just try the next value. This takes extra time and lots of extra time if there are lots of expired rows.

I also need to take care that I don't loose a row if a row I previously got happens to get expired between two calls.

What is the most effective way to iterate through rows when they could be constantly changing?

Comment: Why does the order have to be dense?

Comment: this is not working perfectly because you're here asking ^^ IMHO the solution is not to be found on sql but in the code accessing the table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Running the query twice is possibly the best approach.  But, you can also order all the results, starting with the first value after the number and wrapping around:

```
order by (case when t1.ordering > t2.number then 1 else 2 end),
         t1.ordering
```

If you have 10 rows, then this is fine.  If you have 10,000 then you incur the overhead of sorting all the data, and two queries are probably faster.

Comment: It's for a playlist. It will never have near that many rows. I will give this a try. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You could perform a query using `Min(ordering)`:

```
SELECT @nextOrderingNum = Coalesce(Min(t1.ordering), 0)
FROM table1 t1
WHERE t1.expired > GETDATE()
AND t1.ordering > @prevOrderingNum;
```

If `@nextOrderingNum` is 0 set `@prevOrderingNum` = `@nextOrderingNum` and run again.

Edit, even better instead of running twice just add a sub-query to the `Coalesce`:

```
SELECT @nextOrderingNum = Coalesce(Min(t1.ordering), 
           (SELECT Min(t2.ordering) FROM table1 t2
            WHERE t2.expired > GETDATE()))
FROM table1 t1
WHERE t1.expired > GETDATE()
AND t1.ordering > @prevOrderingNum;
```